# Get token from redirect uri in azure ad

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Here is my controller class code

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Users')")
   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String helloWorld() {
      return "Hello World!";
   }
```

In azure portal I have set the redirect uri as http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure
When I hit on localhost:8080 it returns me hello world. Along with this, it returns a code on redirect uri.
How can I retrieve that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using **`getParameter`**,

```
  private final static String CODE = "code";

  String code = httpRequest.getParameter(CODE);
```

Here is an [`example`](https://github.com/yoshioterada/Office-365-Excel-REST-API-for-Java/blob/2357eb20a9fce0ed88cb71779a94adce4cb7ec01/src/main/java/com/yoshio3/restclient/services/adauth/OAuth2Service.java).

Comment: how do i get the httpRequest object?

Comment: https://github.com/yoshioterada/Office-365-Excel-REST-API-for-Java/blob/2357eb20a9fce0ed88cb71779a94adce4cb7ec01/src/main/java/com/yoshio3/servletfilter/AzureADAuthServletFilter.java